# Home screen launcher Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have 5 Fragments and of course my .MainActivity.

```
MainActivity
FragOne
FragTwo
---
FragFive
```

and then:

```
activity_main.xml
app_bar_main.xml
content_main.xml
nav_header_main.xml
lay1.xml
lay2.xml
---
lay5.xml
```

When the application is loaded it's a blank screen but then obviously when I click the navigation bar the pages will load.

My question is, is there anyway I can use a fragment as my launcher page, because if I tried making a home page on any other activity like content_main or acivity_main, obviously then it would show on every page which I don't want.
But then if I made a new activity and set that as the launcher,obviously that would work but then my navigation bar would be missing I presume? What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: why don't you pre-select a fragment from navigation bar?

Comment: @JunaidHafeez how would I go about that? (My first app so kinda new)

Comment: add your code please, so can tell you.

Comment: @JunaidHafeez which bit do you need? MainActivity.java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is not that big a problem. Just load a fragment using `SupportFragmentManager` in your `MainActivity`. If this Fragment is a one time view only (before you change to your other fragments using Navigation Drawer), then a simple loading of your launcher Fragment in the MainActivity is enough.

Example for loading it once in MainActivity:

In your `onCreate` method in MainActivity :

```
///////////Setting up Fragment as Starting Page////////////
LauncherFragment fragment = new LauncherFragment();
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment,"launcher");
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

This Launcher Fragment won't be seen after you change to other Fragments using NavigationDrawer (unless you call it somewhere else, which according to your question you don't want)

---

If instead of using separate LauncherFragment you decide you want to load FragOne itself, you will need to manually highlight your Drawer's First item (FragOne) after setting up FragOne

```
navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);       ////Set Navigation drawer manually
```

Comment: navigationView came up red, does something need to be imported?

Comment: You must have navigationView defined in your MainActivity, `NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);`

Comment: navigationView is linked to your NavigationDrawer.

Comment: I do have it defined.

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol navigationView, am I putting navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);   in the right place?

Comment: You sure its defined in your onCreate() in MainActivity? If it is, um, try to Rebuild your Project.

Comment: Do not use `navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);` until and unless you are loading FragOne instead of a new LauncherFragment! I specified that in the answer.

Comment: And add these codes after you see the declaration of navigationView in your onCreate() in MainActivity. If you put it before the declaration it'll put up an error. (think this is what might have happened)

Comment: Sure. Glad to be of help. Next time onwards, do try to give more clarity to your questions and ofcourse, **some Experimentation with the codes would have certainly got you this answer** :D